# Custom countdown second timer

Tags: java, object-oriented, timer

I'm making a card game and I found useful to include a 60 second countdown timer. Here is my approach:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class SecondTimer {

    private Timer timer;
    private int countDown;
    private int secondsLeft;

    public SecondTimer() {
        timer = new Timer();
    }

    public void reset() {
        secondsLeft = countDown;
        // Decrease seconds left every 1 second.
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                secondsLeft--;
                if (secondsLeft == 0) {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }

    public void setCountDown(int seconds) {
        this.countDown = seconds;
    }

    public int getSecondsLeft() {
        return secondsLeft;
    }
}
```

Is this considered clean? How can I test such classes?

Comment: What is hooked up to this code? How is the remaining time displayed? Is it supposed to trigger some action at the end of 60 seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Avoid using `java.util.Timer`. See [Checking if a Java Timer is cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13880202/1310566) and [java.util.Timer: Is it deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213109/java-util-timer-is-it-deprecated) Instead use a `ScheduledExecutorService`.
- When changing to a `ScheduledExecutorService`, don't cancel or shutdown your `ScheduledExecutorService`, instead cancel the `FutureTask` that you will get when scheduling a task.
- Don't decrease a counter once a second. Nothing guarantees that it will be called with exactly 1000 ms periodicity.

In your `reset` method, use `System.nanoTime()` ([not `System.currentTimeMillis`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/351565/1310566)) to calculate when the time is up, such as:

```
this.targetTime = System.nanoTime() + seconds * 1_000_000_000;
```

Then calculate in `getSecondsLeft`, by using `System.nanoTime()` again, how many seconds remain until the target nanosecond value has been reached.